# Change multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I'm currently trying to change multiple element's values.

However, my script only work using the element ID, and I can't have more than one ID. What is the alternative, since I don't know how to use getElementsByClassName..

HTML:

```
<select name="valores" id="valores" class="valores" onchange="trocaValores(this.value)">
<option value="v01" selected="selected">Mensal</option>
<option value="v02">Trimestral 5% de desconto</option>
<option value="v03">Semestral 10% de desconto</option>
<option value="v04">Anual 15% de desconto</option>
</select>
```

jScript:

```
function trocaValores(obj) {

combo2=document.getElementById('valores');

for (x=0;x<combo2.length;x++){
    linha=combo2.options[x].value;
    document.getElementById(linha).style.display = "none";
}
//document.getElementById("000").style.display = "none";
//document.pesquisa.cidades.value
itemcombo=combo2.options[combo2.selectedIndex].value;
obj2=document.getElementById(itemcombo);
if (obj2){
    obj2.style.display = '';
}

};
```

And this is what I need to change:

```
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v01"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> mensais </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v02" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> trimestral </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v03" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> semestral </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v04" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> anual </span>
```

PS: I have three blocks like that, so I have three v01, v02..

Thanks!

@EDIT:

Example:

Product ONE:

```
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v01"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> mensais </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v02" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> trimestral </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v03" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> semestral </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v04" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> anual </span>
```

Product TWO:

```
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v01"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> mensais </span>
<span class="moeda soft-strong" id="v02" style="display:none"><sup><h4>R$ 16.90</h4> </sup> trimestral </span>
```

[...]

When changing pricing to product ONE, I need that the monthly price (translation: mensais) of the product TWO change, when changing the quaterly (translation: trimenstral), change of the two products.... and so on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery or pure javascript?  Because if you are using jQuery you could use jQuery selectors to search the DOM and find the elements.

```
$('#valores').change(function() {
    $('span[class^="moeda"]').hide();

    //$(this) would be the combo box and .val() will 
    //give you the value of the selected item
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

This is all you'd need to do if you used jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/S8X6k/

@Update

```
$('#valores').change(function () {
    //Get and hold onto all the spans.  
    //This helps with not needing to search 
    //the DOM each time, one and done
    var spans = $('div[id^="product"] span');

    $(spans).hide();

    //$(this) would be the combo box and .val() will 
    //give you the value of the selected item.
    //Now all we need to do is search, (filter), the
    //set of stored spans for the ones that have an
    //id that starts with the selected value from the
    //combo box.
    $(spans).filter('[id^="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/UBEm2/4/

Comment: Hi, it's pure JavaScript.. but I can use jQuery if necessary.

Comment: This is a very important question for the OP.  But it belongs in a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It doesn't doesn't hurt to use jQuery it just makes righting javascript a little easier, in my opinion.

Comment: @mjhm I know I didn't mean to click in the answer section.

Comment: I was testing here and unfortunately still can't make it work with more than one block. I've edited my question.

Comment: @RodrigoB. OK, just so I'm sure I understand what you're trying to do here, is you want to display the span for the selected value in each of the product blocks?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is like `getElementById`.

```
 var x=document.getElementById("the_id") //getElementById method

 var y=document.getElementsByClassName("the_class") //getElementsByClassName method
```

You type the class name in just like you'd type the id in.

---Edit:---

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object.

So do something like this:

```
 var first=document.getElementsByClassName("the_class");

 document.write(first[0]);
```

*Use document.write for testing purposes only.

---

Now if you wanted the price to change at the beginning of your script make a variable:
`var price="R$ 16.90";`

Then to change the price do:
`price*0.95  //5% discount`
`price*0.90  //10% discount`
`price*0.85  //15% discount`

Comment: Hi, but when using GetElementsByClassName I receive this error in my console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined /Thanks!

Comment: @user3598057 This is because getElementsByClassName returns a node list of all the matching elements (meaning all elements that have the class). You have to iterate through the list you get from calling getElementsByClassName (e.g. with a regular for loop). var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"). And then spans[0] to get the first span.